# Changing the distance to my node label

Tags: tikz-node

```
\begin{tikzpicture}



\draw[<-] (0,0) -- (1.5,0) node[anchor=south] {3N} -- (3,0) node [anchor=330, node distance=10cm] {$\theta$};

\draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,2) node[anchor=west] {4N} -- (0,4);

\draw[->] (3,0) -- (1.5,2) node[anchor=south west] {X} -- (0,4);



\end{tikzpicture}
```

I'm trying to increase the distance to the node label, as it is too close to the corner of the triangle, however I don't want to move the other labels, how do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

like this?

[image]

for edge labels is used `tikz` library `quotes`, for angle "theta" `angle`. corners of triangle is defined by `\coordinate`. they are needed to positioned  `\theta`.

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, arrows.meta, positioning, quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
\coordinate (a);
\coordinate[right=3cm of a] (b);
\coordinate[above=4cm of a] (c);
\draw[-Straight Barb] (b) edge ["3N"]   (a)
                      (b) edge ["X" ']    (c)
                      (a)  to  ["4N"]   (c);
\pic[angle eccentricity=1, "$\theta$"] {angle = c--b--a};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

if you for example like to add names of corners and draw locus at ``theta`, than you can obtain this by:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, arrows.meta, positioning, quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
\coordinate[label=below:A] (a);
\coordinate[label=below:B, right=3cm of a] (b);
\coordinate[label=above:C, above=4cm of a] (c);
\draw[-Straight Barb] (3,0) edge ["3N"]   (0,0)
                      (3,0) edge ["X" ']  (0,4)
                      (0,0)  to  ["4N"]   (0,4);
\pic[draw, angle radius=7mm, angle eccentricity=0.7, "$\theta$"] {angle = c--b--a};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it's the best solution, but labels and `label distance` can help:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[latex-,label distance=4mm] (0,0) -- node[midway,above=1mm] {3N} (3,0) node [label={[anchor=mid]160:$\theta$}] {};
  \draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (0,2) node[right=1mm] {4N} -- (0,4);
  \draw[-latex] (3,0) -- node[midway,above right] {X} (0,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note also that if you need to draw lot's of angles, the `angle` library may be useful.

Answer (score 2):

A short solution with `coordinate`. Define a `coordinate` at corner point, then use `left`, `right`, `above` or `below` and adjust it's parameters of node at this coordinate.

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [latex-] (0,0) -- (3,0) coordinate (A) node[midway, above] {3N} ;
\node at (A) [left=5mm, above=0.1mm ] {$\theta$}; 
\draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (0,2) node[anchor=west] {4N} -- (0,4);
\draw[-latex] (3,0) -- (1.5,2) node[anchor=south west] {X} -- (0,4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```